# Couchdb view search by numeric key

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-2.0, couchdb-mango

I have couchdb setup to have documents like below

```
   {
    "_id": "id",
    "_rev": "rev",
    "docType": "CLAIM",
    "createDate": 1633074806,
    "customerClaimNumber": "CCN101",
    "claimID": "CLID101"
    }
```

Requirement is to have claims returned (claim id and customerclaim number) based on the createDate between start of day to end of day. CreateDate is epoch timestamp (an integer)

I have written the below view

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.docType =="CLAIM" && doc.claimDate && doc.customerClaimNumber) {
  emit([doc.claimDate], doc.customerClaimNumber, doc.claimID);
  }
}
```

I am looking at the recommendation to achieve search based on the createDate field (integer)

Comment: Before moving onto search consider what is happening here.  [emit](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/query-server/javascript.html#emit) doesn't take 3 parameters, it takes 2. Also, why `[doc.claimDate]`? You are indexing a single value as an array,

Answer (score 1):

Well eventually i got this done by creating the view as

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.docType =="CLAIM" && doc.claimDate && doc.customerClaimNumber) {
  emit(doc.claimDate, {vendorClaimNumber: doc.customerClaimNumber, blockchainClaimID: doc.claimID});
  }
}
```

and then calling the view

_view/viewname?startkey=1600000212&endkey=1600010212